# Creating a four-way grid splitter in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridsplitter

In my WPF app, I have four separate quadrants, each with it's own grid and data.  The four grids are separated by GridSplitters.  The GridSplitters allow the user to resize each box by selecting either a horizontal or vertical splitter.

I am trying to allow the user to resize the grids by **selecting the center point** (*circled in red*).
[image: Four quadrants separated by Grid Splitters]

I expected to have a four-way mouse pointer that could be used to drag up, down, left, and right.  But, I only have the option to move windows up and down... or left and right.

[image: Four way pointer]

---

What I've tried:

```
<Grid> <!-- Main Grid that holds A, B, C, and D -->
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="gridA" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <Grid x:Name="gridC" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <Grid x:Name="gridB" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <Grid x:Name="gridD" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: Simple example showing four quadrants with the example code]

Comment: Hey! I've been working on an answer for you for the past two days, almost got everything to work, only a few things to fix are left. Are you still interested?

Comment: @ArtemK Of course!

Comment: Is there something preventing you form accepting my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me begin by changing your XAML a little bit, since right now we have four distinct `GridSplitters`, but two is enough:

```
<Grid Name="SplitGrid">    
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="GridA" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="Red" />
    <Grid x:Name="GridC" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="Orange" />
    <Grid x:Name="GridB" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Background="Green" />
    <Grid x:Name="GridD" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Background="Yellow" />

    <GridSplitter x:Name="VerticalSplitter" 
                  Grid.Column="1" 
                  Grid.Row="0" 
                  Grid.RowSpan="3"     
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Width="5" 
                  Background="Black" />

    <GridSplitter x:Name="HorizontalSplitter" 
                  Grid.Column="0" 
                  Grid.Row="1" 
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                  Height="5" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Background="Black" />
</Grid>
```

What is more important about this markup is that we now have an intersection point between two splitters:

[image]

In order to drag two splitters at a time, we need to know when should we. For that purpose, let's define a `Boolean` flag:

```
public partial class View : Window
{
    private bool _mouseIsDownOnBothSplitters;
}
```

We need to update the flag whenever the user clicks on either of the splitters (note that `Preview` events are used - `GridSplitter` implementation marks `Mouse` events as `Handled`):

```
void UpdateMouseStatusOnSplittersHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateMouseStatusOnSplitters(e);
}

VerticalSplitter.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += UpdateMouseStatusOnSplittersHandler;
HorizontalSplitter.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += UpdateMouseStatusOnSplittersHandler;

VerticalSplitter.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += UpdateMouseStatusOnSplittersHandler;
HorizontalSplitter.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += UpdateMouseStatusOnSplittersHandler;
```

The `UpdateMouseStatusOnSplitters` is the core method here. WPF does not provide multiple layer hit testing "out of the box", [so we'll have to do a custom one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/hit-testing-in-the-visual-layer):

```
private void UpdateMouseStatusOnSplitters(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{    
    bool horizontalSplitterWasHit = false;
    bool verticalSplitterWasHit = false;

    HitTestResultBehavior HitTestAllElements(HitTestResult hitTestResult)
    {
        return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
    }

    //We determine whether we hit our splitters in a filter function because only it tests the visual tree 
    //HitTestAllElements apparently only tests the logical tree
    HitTestFilterBehavior IgnoreNonGridSplitters(DependencyObject hitObject)
    {
        if (hitObject == SplitGrid)
        {
            return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
        }

        if (hitObject is GridSplitter)
        {
            if (hitObject == HorizontalSplitter)
            {
                horizontalSplitterWasHit = true;

                return HitTestFilterBehavior.ContinueSkipChildren;
            }
            if (hitObject == VerticalSplitter)
            {
                verticalSplitterWasHit = true;

                return HitTestFilterBehavior.ContinueSkipChildren;
            }
        }

        return HitTestFilterBehavior.ContinueSkipSelfAndChildren;
    }

    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(SplitGrid, IgnoreNonGridSplitters, HitTestAllElements, new PointHitTestParameters(e.GetPosition(SplitGrid)));

    _mouseIsDownOnBothSplitters = horizontalSplitterWasHit && verticalSplitterWasHit;
}
```

Now we can implement the concurrent dragging. This will be done via a handler for `DragDelta`. However, there are a few caveats:

1. We only need to implement the handler for the splitter that is on top (in my case that'll be the `HorizontalSplitter`)
2. The `Change` value in `DragDeltaEventArgs` [is bugged](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/95d7cea8-1102-4b36-a811-5973cd7db357/dragdeltaeventargs-verticalhorizontal-change-values-seem-to-compound?forum=wpf), the `_lastHorizontalSplitterHorizontalDragChange` is a workaround
3. To actually "drag" the other splitter, we'll have to change the dimensions of our `Column/RowDefinitions`. In order to avoid weird clipping behavior (the splitter dragging the column/row with it), [we'll have to use the size of it in pixels as the the size of it in stars](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/GridSplitter.cs,4fe22533ef9ba02f,references)

So, with that out of the way, here's the relevant handler:

```
private void HorizontalSplitter_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if (_mouseIsDownOnBothSplitters)
    {
        var firstColumn = SplitGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0];
        var thirdColumn = SplitGrid.ColumnDefinitions[2];

        var horizontalOffset = e.HorizontalChange - _lastHorizontalSplitterHorizontalDragChange;

        var maximumColumnWidth = firstColumn.ActualWidth + thirdColumn.ActualWidth;

        var newProposedFirstColumnWidth = firstColumn.ActualWidth + horizontalOffset;
        var newProposedThirdColumnWidth = thirdColumn.ActualWidth - horizontalOffset;

        var newActualFirstColumnWidth = newProposedFirstColumnWidth < 0 ? 0 : newProposedFirstColumnWidth;

        var newActualThirdColumnWidth = newProposedThirdColumnWidth < 0 ? 0 : newProposedThirdColumnWidth;

        firstColumn.Width = new GridLength(newActualFirstColumnWidth, GridUnitType.Star);
        thirdColumn.Width = new GridLength(newActualThirdColumnWidth, GridUnitType.Star);

        _lastHorizontalSplitterHorizontalDragChange = e.HorizontalChange;
    }
}
```

Now, this is *almost* a full solution. It, however, suffers from the fact that even if you move your mouse horizontally outside of the grid, the `VerticalSplitter` still moves with it, which is inconsistent with the default behavior. In order to counteract this, let's add this check to the handler's code:

```
if (_mouseIsDownOnBothSplitters)
{
   var mousePositionRelativeToGrid = Mouse.GetPosition(SplitGrid);
   if (mousePositionRelativeToGrid.X > 0 && mousePositionRelativeToGrid.X < SplitGrid.ActualWidth)
   {
       //The rest of the handler's code
   }
}
```

Finally, we need to reset our `_lastHorizontalSplitterHorizontalDragChange` to zero when the dragging is over:

```
HorizontalSplitter.DragCompleted += (o, e) => _lastHorizontalSplitterHorizontalDragChange = 0;
```

I hope it is not too daring of me to leave the implementation of the cursor's image change to you.